# How much info can I store in a cookie?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swf

Im developing a flash game and I'd like to know how much info can I store in a browser cookie.

The game is simple, but it needs to store several variables in order to save all the details of your current progress.

The game is only one swf file, no server, no nothing.

I need to know how should I use the cookies to achieve this, and if they have the posibility of doing it, of course.

(several = 200 variables i.e)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is important to note that Flash cookies (or Local Shared Objects, as they are called) are different from browser cookies stored by webpages and JavaScript.

From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) on Local Shared Objects:

> By default, a Flash application may
>   store up to 100kb of data to user's
>   hard drive (browser cookies have a
>   limit of just 4kb). The defined
>   storage sizes are 0kb, 10kb, 100kb,
>   1Mb, 10Mb, and Unlimited. If the
>   current limit is exceeded, the user is
>   shown a dialog requesting storage
>   space of the next size. The user may
>   override the amount manually by
>   clicking the Flash application with
>   right mouse button and selecting
>   Settings; however, this applies only
>   to the domain of the Flash movie. If
>   the selected setting is smaller than
>   the current data size, the data is
>   deleted.

Comment: Didnt know that, thx.

Comment: Users can also disable Local Shared Objects by setting the storage limit to 0kb. Make sure to check that and don't let you application crash because of it.

Comment: @Artemix, you can interact with JavaScript from flash using `ExternalInterface` and set normal cookies as well. Additionally, you can have flash send XHRs (AJAX) to a server and store data in a database, or session.

Comment: Maybe Im wrong, but I think I cant call any JS function when I have only a swf file to work with, most sites (game portals mostly) work with one swf file only, and thats all.

Answer (score 4):

Browser cookies are generally limited to 4k, Flash LSOs default to 100k but the user and raise or lower this I think: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

- Browser cookies need to be transferred back and forth between the client and the server when each page is loaded, which can slow down a site's loading speed.
- The new HTML 5 client storage APIs can provide a much better solution to storing data on the client side. This can, of course, be transferred back and forth between the client and the server when necessary. [Check this article for more info.](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/)

Comment: Im making a Flash game, but thx anw.